# Determine which camera used by Android camera activity

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I'm writing an Android app that relies upon a user periodically taking pictures.  It has been documented that Android will return an image flipped *and* rotated at 90 degrees if a picture was taken from the front-facing camera.  I am able to successfully reorient the picture when this happens.  The problem is that I don't know how to tell *when* the front-facing camera is used.  By knowing when the front-facing camera was used while taking a picture, I can determine whether I should be re-orienting it or not.

Is there any way to determine, preferably during onActivityResult(), which camera was used?  Is there another practice used to help determine and fix picture orientation?

Here is my Camera activity launch code.  Very straight forward:

```
    private void startCameraIntent(String name) {
    try {
        String fileName = MontageConstants.APP_DATA_FOLDER + "/" + name + "/" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg";
        Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PIC_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't take picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120421/how-to-rotate-android-device-camera-previewlibgdx/22120629#22120629
Might be helpful to you.

Comment: That took me down the exact path that I needed.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Navjot Singh - I found the information that I needed at an answer he posted: [How to rotate android device camera preview(libgdx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120421/how-to-rotate-android-device-camera-previewlibgdx/22120629#22120629).  Effectively, you can read Exif tags in a stored JPEG file with the class ExifInterface.  Since I was storing my pictures to file before manipulating them, I simply inserted the file path, got the orientation, and rotated/adjusted correspondingly.

```
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(fileName);
            orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```